# Javascript Codes works in Jsfiddle but didn't work on wordpress page

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

this is my third day of troubleshooting a code that I would love to implement on my WordPress page, preferable as a shortcode to embed on any post/page.

I have enqueued the script, and this is how I did it:

```
function chicken_wings_audiosynth() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'audiosynth', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/audiosynth.js' ), array(), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/audiosynth.js' ) ), true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chicken_wings_audiosynth' );
```

I have viewed my source code, and I can see they are all loaded, my challenge is figuring a way to call the js code on the page.

This is what I got as my output: 
[image: Output image]

and this is what it's supposed to look like:

```js
// Play around with some webkit scroll bars... nothing special, but its interesting to see what can be done :)

var Synth, AudioSynth, AudioSynthInstrument;
! function() {
  var _encapsulated = false;
  var AudioSynthInstance = null;
  var pack = function(c, arg) {
    return [String.fromCharCode(arg & 255, (arg >> 8) & 255), String.fromCharCode(arg & 255, (arg >> 8) & 255, (arg >> 16) & 255, (arg >> 24) & 255)][c];
  };
  var setPrivateVar = function(n, v, w, e) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, n, {
      value: v,
      writable: !!w,
      enumerable: !!e
    });
  };
  var setPublicVar = function(n, v, w) {
    setPrivateVar.call(this, n, v, w, true);
  };
  AudioSynthInstrument = function AudioSynthInstrument() {
    this.__init__.apply(this, arguments);
  };
  var setPriv = setPrivateVar.bind(AudioSynthInstrument.prototype);
  var setPub = setPublicVar.bind(AudioSynthInstrument.prototype);
  setPriv('__init__', function(a, b, c) {
    if (!_encapsulated) {
      throw new Error('AudioSynthInstrument can only be instantiated from the createInstrument method of the AudioSynth object.');
    }
    setPrivateVar.call(this, '_parent', a);
    setPublicVar.call(this, 'name', b);
    setPrivateVar.call(this, '_soundID', c);
  });
  setPub('play', function(note, octave, duration) {
    return this._parent.play(this._soundID, note, octave, duration);
  });
  setPub('generate', function(note, octave, duration) {
    return this._parent.generate(this._soundID, note, octave, duration);
  });
  AudioSynth = function AudioSynth() {
    if (AudioSynthInstance instanceof AudioSynth) {
      return AudioSynthInstance;
    } else {
      this.__init__();
      return this;
    }
  };
  setPriv = setPrivateVar.bind(AudioSynth.prototype);
  setPub = setPublicVar.bind(AudioSynth.prototype);
  setPriv('_debug', false, true);
  setPriv('_bitsPerSample', 16);
  setPriv('_channels', 1);
  setPriv('_sampleRate', 44100, true);
  setPub('setSampleRate', function(v) {
    this._sampleRate = Math.max(Math.min(v | 0, 44100), 4000);
    this._clearCache();
    return this._sampleRate;
  });
  setPub('getSampleRate', function() {
    return this._sampleRate;
  });
  setPriv('_volume', 32768, true);
  setPub('setVolume', function(v) {
    v = parseFloat(v);
    if (isNaN(v)) {
      v = 0;
    }
    v = Math.round(v * 32768);
    this._volume = Math.max(Math.min(v | 0, 32768), 0);
    this._clearCache();
    return this._volume;
  });
  setPub('getVolume', function() {
    return Math.round(this._volume / 32768 * 10000) / 10000;
  });
  setPriv('_notes', {
    'C': 261.63,
    'C#': 277.18,
    'D': 293.66,
    'D#': 311.13,
    'E': 329.63,
    'F': 349.23,
    'F#': 369.99,
    'G': 392.00,
    'G#': 415.30,
    'A': 440.00,
    'A#': 466.16,
    'B': 493.88
  });
  setPriv('_fileCache', [], true);
  setPriv('_temp', {}, true);
  setPriv('_sounds', [], true);
  setPriv('_mod', [function(i, s, f, x) {
    return Math.sin((2 * Math.PI) * (i / s) * f + x);
  }]);
  setPriv('_resizeCache', function() {
    var f = this._fileCache;
    var l = this._sounds.length;
    while (f.length < l) {
      var octaveList = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var noteList = {};
        for (var k in this._notes) {
          noteList[k] = {};
        }
        octaveList.push(noteList);
      }
      f.push(octaveList);
    }
  });
  setPriv('_clearCache', function() {
    this._fileCache = [];
    this._resizeCache();
  });
  setPub('generate', function(sound, note, octave, duration) {
    var thisSound = this._sounds[sound];
    if (!thisSound) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this._sounds.length; i++) {
        if (this._sounds[i].name == sound) {
          thisSound = this._sounds[i];
          sound = i;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (!thisSound) {
      throw new Error('Invalid sound or sound ID: ' + sound);
    }
    var t = (new Date).valueOf();
    this._temp = {};
    octave |= 0;
    octave = Math.min(8, Math.max(1, octave));
    var time = !duration ? 2 : parseFloat(duration);
    if (typeof(this._notes[note]) == 'undefined') {
      throw new Error(note + ' is not a valid note.');
    }
    if (typeof(this._fileCache[sound][octave - 1][note][time]) != 'undefined') {
      if (this._debug) {
        console.log((new Date).valueOf() - t, 'ms to retrieve (cached)');
      }
      return this._fileCache[sound][octave - 1][note][time];
    } else {
      var frequency = this._notes[note] * Math.pow(2, octave - 4);
      var data = [];
      var sampleRate = this._sampleRate;
      var volume = this._volume;
      var channels = this._channels;
      var bitsPerSample = this._bitsPerSample;
      var attack = thisSound.attack(sampleRate, frequency, volume);
      var dampen = thisSound.dampen(sampleRate, frequency, volume);
      var wave = thisSound.wave.bind({
        modulate: this._mod,
        vars: this._temp
      });
      var val = 0;
      var curVol = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < (sampleRate * time); i++) {
        if (i <= sampleRate * attack) {
          curVol = volume * (i / (sampleRate * attack));
        } else {
          curVol = volume * Math.pow((1 - ((i - (sampleRate * attack)) / (sampleRate * (time - attack)))), dampen);
        }

        val = curVol * Math.min(Math.max(wave(i, sampleRate, frequency, volume), -1), 1);
        val = String.fromCharCode(val & 255, (val >>> 8) & 255);
        data.push(val);
      }

      data = data.join('');

      // Format sub-chunk
      var chunk1 = [
        'fmt ', // Sub-chunk identifier
        pack(1, 16), // Chunk length
        pack(0, 1), // Audio format (1 is linear quantization)
        pack(0, channels),
        pack(1, sampleRate),
        pack(1, sampleRate * channels * bitsPerSample / 8), // Byte rate
        pack(0, channels * bitsPerSample / 8),
        pack(0, bitsPerSample)
      ].join('');
      // Data sub-chunk (contains the sound)
      var chunk2 = [
        'data', // Sub-chunk identifier
        pack(1, data.length * channels * bitsPerSample / 8), // Chunk length
        data
      ].join('');
      // Header
      var header = [
        'RIFF',
        pack(1, 4 + (8 + chunk1.length) + (8 + chunk2.length)), // Length
        'WAVE'
      ].join('');
      var out = [header, chunk1, chunk2].join('');
      var dataURI = 'data:audio/wav;base64,' + escape(window.btoa(out));
      this._fileCache[sound][octave - 1][note][time] = dataURI;
      if (this._debug) {
        console.log((new Date).valueOf() - t, 'ms to generate');
      }
      return dataURI;
    }
  });
  setPub('play', function(note, octave, duration) {
    var src = this.generate(note, octave, duration);
    var audio = new Audio(src);
    audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
      audio = null;
    });
    audio.autoplay = true;
    audio.setAttribute('type', 'audio/wav');
    return true;
  });
  setPub('debug', function() {
    this._debug = true;
  });
  setPub('createInstrument', function(sound) {
    var n = 0;
    var found = false;
    if (typeof(sound) == 'string') {
      for (var i = 0; i < this._sounds.length; i++) {
        if (this._sounds[i].name == sound) {
          found = true;
          n = i;
          break;
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (this._sounds[sound]) {
        n = sound;
        sound = this._sounds[n].name;
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      throw new Error('Invalid sound or sound ID: ' + sound);
    }
    _encapsulated = true;
    var ins = new AudioSynthInstrument(this, sound, n);
    _encapsulated = false;
    return ins;
  });
  setPub('listSounds', function() {
    var r = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this._sounds.length; i++) {
      r.push(this._sounds[i].name);
    }
    return r;
  });
  setPriv('__init__', function() {
    this._resizeCache();
  });
  setPub('loadSoundProfile', function() {
    for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
      o = arguments[i];
      if (!(o instanceof Object)) {
        throw new Error('Invalid sound profile.');
      }
      this._sounds.push(o);
    }
    this._resizeCache();
    return true;
  });
  setPub('loadModulationFunction', function() {
    for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
      f = arguments[i];
      if (typeof(f) != 'function') {
        throw new Error('Invalid modulation function.');
      }
      this._mod.push(f);
    }
    return true;
  });
  AudioSynthInstance = new AudioSynth();
  Synth = AudioSynthInstance;
}();

Synth.loadModulationFunction(
  function(i, sampleRate, frequency, x) {
    return 1 * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * ((i / sampleRate) * frequency) + x);
  },
  function(i, sampleRate, frequency, x) {
    return 1 * Math.sin(4 * Math.PI * ((i / sampleRate) * frequency) + x);
  },
  function(i, sampleRate, frequency, x) {
    return 1 * Math.sin(8 * Math.PI * ((i / sampleRate) * frequency) + x);
  },
  function(i, sampleRate, frequency, x) {
    return 1 * Math.sin(0.5 * Math.PI * ((i / sampleRate) * frequency) + x);
  },
  function(i, sampleRate, frequency, x) {
    return 1 * Math.sin(0.25 * Math.PI * ((i / sampleRate) * frequency) + x);
  },
  function(i, sampleRate, frequency, x) {
    return 0.5 * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * ((i / sampleRate) * frequency) + x);
  },
  function(i, sampleRate, frequency, x) {
    return 0.5 * Math.sin(4 * Math.PI * ((i / sampleRate) * frequency) + x);
  },
  function(i, sampleRate, frequency, x) {
    return 0.5 * Math.sin(8 * Math.PI * ((i / sampleRate) * frequency) + x);
  },
  function(i, sampleRate, frequency, x) {
    return 0.5 * Math.sin(0.5 * Math.PI * ((i / sampleRate) * frequency) + x);
  },
  function(i, sampleRate, frequency, x) {
    return 0.5 * Math.sin(0.25 * Math.PI * ((i / sampleRate) * frequency) + x);
  }
);

Synth.loadSoundProfile({
  name: 'piano',
  attack: function() {
    return 0.002;
  },
  dampen: function(sampleRate, frequency, volume) {
    return Math.pow(0.5 * Math.log((frequency * volume) / sampleRate), 2);
  },
  wave: function(i, sampleRate, frequency, volume) {
    var base = this.modulate[0];
    return this.modulate[1](
      i,
      sampleRate,
      frequency,
      Math.pow(base(i, sampleRate, frequency, 0), 2) +
      (0.75 * base(i, sampleRate, frequency, 0.25)) +
      (0.1 * base(i, sampleRate, frequency, 0.5))
    );
  }
}, {
  name: 'organ',
  attack: function() {
    return 0.3
  },
  dampen: function(sampleRate, frequency) {
    return 1 + (frequency * 0.01);
  },
  wave: function(i, sampleRate, frequency) {
    var base = this.modulate[0];
    return this.modulate[1](
      i,
      sampleRate,
      frequency,
      base(i, sampleRate, frequency, 0) +
      0.5 * base(i, sampleRate, frequency, 0.25) +
      0.25 * base(i, sampleRate, frequency, 0.5)
    );
  }
}, {
  name: 'acoustic',
  attack: function() {
    return 0.002;
  },
  dampen: function() {
    return 1;
  },
  wave: function(i, sampleRate, frequency) {

    var vars = this.vars;
    vars.valueTable = !vars.valueTable ? [] : vars.valueTable;
    if (typeof(vars.playVal) == 'undefined') {
      vars.playVal = 0;
    }
    if (typeof(vars.periodCount) == 'undefined') {
      vars.periodCount = 0;
    }

    var valueTable = vars.valueTable;
    var playVal = vars.playVal;
    var periodCount = vars.periodCount;

    var period = sampleRate / frequency;
    var p_hundredth = Math.floor((period - Math.floor(period)) * 100);

    var resetPlay = false;

    if (valueTable.length <= Math.ceil(period)) {

      valueTable.push(Math.round(Math.random()) * 2 - 1);

      return valueTable[valueTable.length - 1];

    } else {

      valueTable[playVal] = (valueTable[playVal >= (valueTable.length - 1) ? 0 : playVal + 1] + valueTable[playVal]) * 0.5;

      if (playVal >= Math.floor(period)) {
        if (playVal < Math.ceil(period)) {
          if ((periodCount % 100) >= p_hundredth) {
            // Reset
            resetPlay = true;
            valueTable[playVal + 1] = (valueTable[0] + valueTable[playVal + 1]) * 0.5;
            vars.periodCount++;
          }
        } else {
          resetPlay = true;
        }
      }

      var _return = valueTable[playVal];
      if (resetPlay) {
        vars.playVal = 0;
      } else {
        vars.playVal++;
      }

      return _return;

    }
  }
}, {
  name: 'edm',
  attack: function() {
    return 0.002;
  },
  dampen: function() {
    return 1;
  },
  wave: function(i, sampleRate, frequency) {
    var base = this.modulate[0];
    var mod = this.modulate.slice(1);
    return mod[0](
      i,
      sampleRate,
      frequency,
      mod[9](
        i,
        sampleRate,
        frequency,
        mod[2](
          i,
          sampleRate,
          frequency,
          Math.pow(base(i, sampleRate, frequency, 0), 3) +
          Math.pow(base(i, sampleRate, frequency, 0.5), 5) +
          Math.pow(base(i, sampleRate, frequency, 1), 7)
        )
      ) +
      mod[8](
        i,
        sampleRate,
        frequency,
        base(i, sampleRate, frequency, 1.75)
      )
    );
  }
});


function AudioSynthView() {

  var isMobile = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile/i);
  if (isMobile) {
    var evtListener = ['touchstart', 'touchend'];
  } else {
    var evtListener = ['mousedown', 'mouseup'];
  }

  var __audioSynth = new AudioSynth();
  __audioSynth.setVolume(0.5);
  var __octave = 4;

  // Change octave
  var fnChangeOctave = function(x) {

    x |= 0;

    __octave += x;

    __octave = Math.min(5, Math.max(3, __octave));

    var octaveName = document.getElementsByName('OCTAVE_LABEL');
    var i = octaveName.length;
    while (i--) {
      var val = parseInt(octaveName[i].getAttribute('value'));
      octaveName[i].innerHTML = (val + __octave);
    }

    document.getElementById('OCTAVE_LOWER').innerHTML = __octave - 1;
    document.getElementById('OCTAVE_UPPER').innerHTML = __octave + 1;

  };

  // Key bindings, notes to keyCodes.
  var keyboard = {

    /* 2 */
    50: 'C#,-1',

    /* 3 */
    51: 'D#,-1',

    /* 5 */
    53: 'F#,-1',

    /* 6 */
    54: 'G#,-1',

    /* 7 */
    55: 'A#,-1',

    /* 9 */
    57: 'C#,0',

    /* 0 */
    48: 'D#,0',

    /* + */
    187: 'F#,0',
    61: 'F#,0',

    /* Q */
    81: 'C,-1',

    /* W */
    87: 'D,-1',

    /* E */
    69: 'E,-1',

    /* R */
    82: 'F,-1',

    /* T */
    84: 'G,-1',

    /* Y */
    89: 'A,-1',

    /* U */
    85: 'B,-1',

    /* I */
    73: 'C,0',

    /* O */
    79: 'D,0',

    /* P */
    80: 'E,0',

    /* [ */
    219: 'F,0',

    /* ] */
    221: 'G,0',

    /* A */
    65: 'G#,0',

    /* S */
    83: 'A#,0',

    /* F */
    70: 'C#,1',

    /* G */
    71: 'D#,1',

    /* J */
    74: 'F#,1',

    /* K */
    75: 'G#,1',

    /* L */
    76: 'A#,1',

    /* Z */
    90: 'A,0',

    /* X */
    88: 'B,0',

    /* C */
    67: 'C,1',

    /* V */
    86: 'D,1',

    /* B */
    66: 'E,1',

    /* N */
    78: 'F,1',

    /* M */
    77: 'G,1',

    /* , */
    188: 'A,1',

    /* . */
    190: 'B,1'

  };

  var reverseLookupText = {};
  var reverseLookup = {};

  // Create a reverse lookup table.
  for (var i in keyboard) {

    var val;

    switch (i | 0) {

      case 187:
        val = 61;
        break;

      case 219:
        val = 91;
        break;

      case 221:
        val = 93;
        break;

      case 188:
        val = 44;
        break;

      case 190:
        val = 46;
        break;

      default:
        val = i;
        break;

    }

    reverseLookupText[keyboard[i]] = val;
    reverseLookup[keyboard[i]] = i;

  }

  // Keys you have pressed down.
  var keysPressed = [];
  var visualKeyboard = null;
  var selectSound = null;

  var fnCreateKeyboard = function(keyboardElement) {
    // Generate keyboard
    // This is our main keyboard element! It's populated dynamically based on what you've set above.
    visualKeyboard = document.getElementById('keyboard');
    selectSound = document.getElementById('sound');

    var iKeys = 0;
    var iWhite = 0;
    var notes = __audioSynth._notes;

    for (var i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
      for (var n in notes) {
        if (n[2] != 'b') {
          var thisKey = document.createElement('div');
          if (n.length > 1) {
            thisKey.className = 'black key';
            thisKey.style.width = '30px';
            thisKey.style.height = '120px';
            thisKey.style.left = (40 * (iWhite - 1)) + 25 + 'px';
          } else {
            thisKey.className = 'white key';
            thisKey.style.width = '40px';
            thisKey.style.height = '200px';
            thisKey.style.left = 40 * iWhite + 'px';
            iWhite++;
          }
          var label = document.createElement('div');
          label.className = 'label';
          label.innerHTML = '<b>' + String.fromCharCode(reverseLookupText[n + ',' + i]) + '</b>' + '<br /><br />' + n.substr(0, 1) +
            '<span name="OCTAVE_LABEL" value="' + i + '">' + (__octave + parseInt(i)) + '</span>' + (n.substr(1, 1) ? n.substr(1, 1) : '');
          thisKey.appendChild(label);
          thisKey.setAttribute('ID', 'KEY_' + n + ',' + i);
          thisKey.addEventListener(evtListener[0], (function(_temp) {
            return function() {
              fnPlayKeyboard({
                keyCode: _temp
              });
            }
          })(reverseLookup[n + ',' + i]));
          visualKeyboard[n + ',' + i] = thisKey;
          visualKeyboard.appendChild(thisKey);
          iKeys++;
        }
      }
    }

    visualKeyboard.style.width = iWhite * 40 + 'px';

    window.addEventListener(evtListener[1], function() {
      n = keysPressed.length;
      while (n--) {
        fnRemoveKeyBinding({
          keyCode: keysPressed[n]
        });
      }
    });

  };

  // Creates our audio player
  var fnPlayNote = function(note, octave) {

    src = __audioSynth.generate(selectSound.value, note, octave, 2);
    container = new Audio(src);
    container.addEventListener('ended', function() {
      container = null;
    });
    container.addEventListener('loadeddata', function(e) {
      e.target.play();
    });
    container.autoplay = false;
    container.setAttribute('type', 'audio/wav');
    /*document.body.appendChild(container);*/
    container.load();
    return container;

  };

  // Detect keypresses, play notes.

  var fnPlayKeyboard = function(e) {

    var i = keysPressed.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (keysPressed[i] == e.keyCode) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    keysPressed.push(e.keyCode);

    switch (e.keyCode) {

      // left
      case 37:
        fnChangeOctave(-1);
        break;

        // right
      case 39:
        fnChangeOctave(1);
        break;

        // space
      case 16:
        break;
        fnPlaySong([
          ['E,0', 8],
          ['D,0', 8],
          ['C,0', 2],
          ['C,0', 8],
          ['D,0', 8],
          ['C,0', 8],
          ['E,0', 8],
          ['D,0', 1],
          ['C,0', 8],
          ['D,0', 8],
          ['E,0', 2],
          ['A,0', 8],
          ['G,0', 8],
          ['E,0', 8],
          ['C,0', 8],
          ['D,0', 1],
          ['A,0', 8],
          ['B,0', 8],
          ['C,1', 2],
          ['B,0', 8],
          ['C,1', 8],
          ['D,1', 8],
          ['C,1', 8],
          ['A,0', 1],
          ['G,0', 8],
          ['A,0', 8],
          ['B,0', 2],
          ['C,1', 8],
          ['B,0', 8],
          ['A,0', 8],
          ['G,0', 8],
          ['A,0', 1]
        ]);
        break;

    }

    if (keyboard[e.keyCode]) {
      if (visualKeyboard[keyboard[e.keyCode]]) {
        visualKeyboard[keyboard[e.keyCode]].style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
        visualKeyboard[keyboard[e.keyCode]].style.marginTop = '5px';
        visualKeyboard[keyboard[e.keyCode]].style.boxShadow = 'none';
      }
      var arrPlayNote = keyboard[e.keyCode].split(',');
      var note = arrPlayNote[0];
      var octaveModifier = arrPlayNote[1] | 0;
      fnPlayNote(note, __octave + octaveModifier);
    } else {
      return false;
    }

  }

  // Remove key bindings once note is done.

  var fnRemoveKeyBinding = function(e) {

    var i = keysPressed.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (keysPressed[i] == e.keyCode) {
        if (visualKeyboard[keyboard[e.keyCode]]) {
          visualKeyboard[keyboard[e.keyCode]].style.backgroundColor = '';
          visualKeyboard[keyboard[e.keyCode]].style.marginTop = '';
          visualKeyboard[keyboard[e.keyCode]].style.boxShadow = '';
        }
        keysPressed.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }

  }

  var fnPlaySong = function(arr) {

    if (arr.length > 0) {

      var noteLen = 1000 * (1 / parseInt(arr[0][1]));
      if (!(arr[0][0] instanceof Array)) {
        arr[0][0] = [arr[0][0]];
      }
      var i = arr[0][0].length;
      var keys = [];
      while (i--) {
        keys.unshift(reverseLookup[arr[0][0][i]]);
        fnPlayKeyboard({
          keyCode: keys[0]
        });
      }
      arr.shift();
      setTimeout(function(array, val) {
        return function() {
          var i = val.length;
          while (i--) {
            fnRemoveKeyBinding({
              keyCode: val[i]
            });
          }
          fnPlaySong(array);
        }
      }(arr, keys), noteLen);

    }

  };

  // Set up global event listeners

  window.addEventListener('keydown', fnPlayKeyboard);
  window.addEventListener('keyup', fnRemoveKeyBinding);
  document.getElementById('-_OCTAVE').addEventListener('click', function() {
    fnChangeOctave(-1);
  });
  document.getElementById('+_OCTAVE').addEventListener('click', function() {
    fnChangeOctave(1);
  });

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'draw', {
    value: fnCreateKeyboard
  });

}

var a = new AudioSynthView();
a.draw();
```

```css
.key {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 1px rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.2);
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.05s ease, background-color 0.05s ease, box-shadow 0.05s ease;
}

.key:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 192, 32);
}

.key .label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.black {
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  z-index: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.5);
}

.title {
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.2);
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sub {
  color: rgb(96, 96, 96);
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
}

.sub a,
.sub a:link,
.sub a:visited,
.sub a:active {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(128, 160, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sub a:hover {
  color: rgb(160, 192, 255);
}

.source a {
  color: rgb(255, 96, 96);
}

.source a:link,
.source a:visited,
.source a:active {
  color: rgb(255, 96, 96);
}

.source a:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 128, 128);
}

.small {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.keyboard-options {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 10px;
}

.keyboard-holder {
  margin: 30px auto;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="keyboard-options">
  Sound
  <select ID="sound">
 <option value="0" selected>Keyboard</option>
 <option value="1">Organ</option>
    <option value="2">Acoustic Guitar</option>
    <option value="3">EDM, bro!</option>
</select>
  <div ID="keyboard" class="keyboard-holder"></div>
  <div class="keyboard-options">
    Range [C<span ID="OCTAVE_LOWER">3</span>-B<span ID="OCTAVE_UPPER">5</span>]
    <input type="button" ID="-_OCTAVE" value="-" />
    <input type="button" ID="+_OCTAVE" value="+" /><br />
    <i>(Use left/right arrows to adjust with keyboard)</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

I solved the issue, it is a cache problem, how do I turn this into a WordPress shortcode

**Edit 2** {Fixed for Shortcode}

```
function my_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    ?> <HTML> <here> ... <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'caption', 'caption_shortcode' );
```

I went over the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output)

Comment: Are you getting any console errors when in your wordpress site? If so what are they?

Comment: Oh, I think I got something related - ```Uncaught ReferenceError: AudioSynthView is not defined
    at (index):567```

Comment: var a = new AudioSynthView();
                a.draw();

Audiosynthview is not defined when called.

What I did before was this:
```
function aud_hook_javascript() {
    ?>
        <script>
          var a = new AudioSynthView();
                a.draw();
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'aud_hook_javascript');
```

When I removed it and added it to my main Javascript, the error disappeared but still not working. But I got this in the console instead: http://prntscr.com/odwkup

Comment: @JonP it is working in firefox http://prntscr.com/odwmiy - just checked. Edit - My bad, it's a cache issue :)

Comment: Already given you the [full working answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/342698/102912)